# Отправка вложений из формы на почту PHP

Tags: php, html

Есть форма.

```
<form data-toggle="validator" class="sendform" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">             
    <h1>Text</h1>
    <p>text</p>                
    <input type="tel" name="phone" required placeholder="Tелефон"><br>
    <input type="text"  name="email" placeholder="E-mail"><br>
    <textarea type="text" name="comment" placeholder="Комментарий"></textarea><br>               
    <input type="file" multiple id="userfile" class="multi" maxlength="3"  data-maxfile="150000" name="userfile[]" accept="pdf|jpg|jpeg|png|xls|xlsx|doc|docx|bmp|mp4" />       
    <button type="submit" class="button">text</button>
    <p>text</p>

    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="150000">
    <input type="hidden" name="files" id="upfiles"> 
</form>
```

Обработчик PHP

```
if (isset($_POST["time_spend"])){

$phone = trim($_POST["phone"]);    
$email = trim($_POST["email"]);
$time_spend = $_POST["time_spend"];


require './PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

$mail->setFrom('email@email.ru');

$mail->addAddress('email@email.ru');  


$mail->Subject = 'Заявка с сайта ('.$forma.')'; 
$mail->isHTML(true);

for($ct=0;$ct<count($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);$ct++)
{
    $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct]));
    $filename =$_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct];
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$ct], $uploadfile)) {
        $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, $filename);
    }
}


$message = "<table>";
```

На почту не приходят вложения. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Использовать функцию mail( ) (http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php)

Comment: Проверьте удалось ли скопировать вложение во временный файл, то есть попадаете ли вы внутрь `if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$ct], $uploadfile)) {`